# alignment/padding in C structure

Tags: c

I am going through a code in my project.

Following is structure defined as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    ULONG gatewayIp;
    UBYTE status;
        UBYTE align;
    UWORD info;
    ULONG magicTemp;
    uword stationCode;
} GatewayStatus;
```

My question is why we are align in between in above structure.

I taught compiler takes care of aligning as mentioned in following link.
http://vcfaq.mvps.org/lang/11.htm

I generalize my question irrespective of above structure 
Under what scenarios we have to align programmatically and what scenarios compiler will do that for us?

Does padding requires if two machine with differient endian types i.e., one m/c is big endian and other is low endian?

Kindly clarify my question.

Thanks!

Comment: What context is this struct from? It wouldn't happen to be in a library that does I/O using binary dumps of this struct, would it?

Comment: I assume it's a bad example because it is related to a dedicated product where developers decided to define this structure in that way; maybe word (2 byte) align. This has nothing to do with compiler aligement.

Comment: What is the C++ tag for if all your content displays C?

Comment: What are the underlying types of `ULONG`, `UBYTE`, `UWORD`, and `uword`?  What are the sizes of those types on your platform?  The compiler will put whatever padding it thinks necessary between elements of the structure.  It will minimize the wasted space while avoiding slowdowns from misaligned data access.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that it's there to make is clear that there will be a pad byte at that location. This could be useful in case someone would like to add a byte field in the future.

Another scenaria is if the struct is used on a system without alignment requirements (which, typically is the case for 8-bit architectures), but still should have the same layout as on a large machine. In this case, the struct definition need the explicit padding.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler align the datas for maximum alignable bytes by default, which is depending on the machine. For linux GCC compiler is doing 4 byte alignment by default.

If we want to align 8, 16, 32, etc... bytes, we need to tell explicitly to the compiler.